# Dismissing parent view controller of double modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have the current setup where `->` is a modal presentation (`presentViewController()`):

```
ViewController A -> NavigationController B:
    ViewController C
    ViewController D -> ViewController E
```

I am currently inside `ViewController E`. I would like to dismiss all the modally presented view controllers so that I can get back to `ViewController A`. It seems that whatever I try on `ViewController E`, (`dismissViewController()` with `self`, `parentViewController`, `presentViewController`, `navigationController`) I am easily able to dismiss `ViewController E` but cannot dismiss `ViewController B` and all of its sub view controllers. It seems to me that I have lost all references to it yet when `ViewController E` is dismissed, `ViewController D` (a sub view controller of the navigation controller `NavigationController B)` is still visible.

Any help to dismiss both `ViewController E` and `NavigationController B` and all of its sub view controllers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: are you using Storyboards?

Comment: Yes. All the view controllers I mentioned are view controllers in the Main storyboard

Comment: Check my answer, it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an unwind segue. I'm unaware of any way to do it outside of a storyboard but essentially you would set an unwind segue from `ViewControllerE` to `ViewControllerA` and then when in `E`, perform a segue as you would normally: `self.performSegue('UnwindSegue', sender: self)`

[This](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/) is a pretty good article on the whole topic. Essentially what happens is the view controller stack unwinds all the way to the exit point of the unwind segue once its triggered so you can go from `E` to `A` no problem. You can also have multiple unwind segues through the app, just make sure to give them identifiers.

This is really useful in scenarios like logout, where the user might be five or six view controllers deep but your app has a side menu that they can use to log out at any point. You can just unwind all the way to the first view controller.